# Find the positive difference of all possible values

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This problem is quite challenging to me. It is highly appreciated if someone can help me with it or give me an hint. Thank you very much!

> Find the positive difference of all possible values of $x^3 +1/
> x^3$ given that $x^2 +1/x^2 = 7$.

Comment: How many solutions do you think there are to $x^2+1/x^2=7$?

Comment: I can calculate x using the second equation and then plug them in the first equation. That is very complicated. Is there an easy way to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: You will find there are only two possible values for $x^3+1/x^3$ with that constraint. It is not too hard to subtract one from the other.

Comment: Actually it is easy, not complicated. But JimmyK4542 has an alternative approach below if you prefer that.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If you let $$a = x+\dfrac{1}{x}$$ then you have $$x^2+\dfrac{1}{x^2} = \left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^2-2 = a^2-2,$$ and $$x^3+\dfrac{1}{x^3} = \left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^3 - 3\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right) = a^3-3a.$$

Do you see how this helps?